# Getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError while opening bootstrap modal in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

while selecting options of select getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError but modal getting opened.

How to get rid of this error?

```
<select  #pageOptions="ngModel" class="form-control pull-right col-lg-4"   (change)="changePageOptions(pageSelect)" [(ngModel)]="page_options[i].option" name="pageOptions{{i}}">
  <option value="">More Options</option>
  <option value="move_page">Move Page</option>
  <option value="delete_page">Delete Page</option>
  <option value="copy_page">Copy Page</option>
</select>
```

And js code:

```
    changePageOptions(content){

    this.modalService1.open(content).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a lifecycle error (in case you wanted to know).

To get rid of this, trigger change detection again :

```
changePageOptions(content) {
  this.modalService1.open(content).result.then((result) => {
    setTimeout(() => this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`);
  }, (reason) => {
    setTimeout(() => this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`);
  });
}
```

Comment: changePageOptions(content,value){

    this.modalService1.open(content).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });

    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
still can't get rid of this error

Comment: Did you try my code ? And please post the full error trace so that I can locate your exact issue.

Comment: ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.

Comment: I don't see you setting a boolean in your code. Could you post the code where you set a boolean to true ?

Comment: I have not set any boolean value in my code still it is giving the same error

Comment: You sure have, because your error says you have. I'm not making this up for the sake of being right you know ;) This means you think your error is in the modal code (the `changePageOptions` method), but it's actually not. It is usually in the lifecycle methods, such as  `ngOninit` or `ngAfterViewInit`. Could you check those methods ?